# Tor Browser keeps leading me to download page of Google Chrome when I enter a particular website

Tags: connection

So I just downloaded and started using Tor Browser and since I live in one of the countries where Tor is banned, I make my connection via a bridge (might be useful info idk :) Whenever I try to enter a specific website, tor browser automaticially leads me to page for downloading google chrome which is quite interesting.

Comment: Maybe the website is only designed for Chrome? And it is asking you because Tor browser is based on FireFox.

Comment: Before started using Tor Browser, I was using Firefox and had no such issue. It's a weird thing.

Comment: In that case.. More information is needed to figure out why. If you are willing to share, that is. But likely cause by the user agent or tor browers's anonymity feature.

Comment: what do you mean by user agent?

Comment: The user agent is something any browser sends along with every HTTP request so the server could know which browser it is and reply with (possible) browser specific content (ex: bug workarounds). See more at WikiPedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_agent

Comment: the website I'm trying to enter is simply a crypto currency market viewing site, maybe they won't let Tor browser in since it's banned in my country. Would that make sense?